# I can't use other flag options after raising one, and there's no feedback saying why

Tags: bug, flagging, user-interface

I just now [flagged a particular post as Rude/Abusive](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/94490/1204). I then had a further detail to report about the post (the username is offensive), but when I went to use the flag dialog again, I found that despite being visibly enabled, I could not actually select the last option for "in need of moderator intervention" to supply a custom message pointing it out:

[image: "you already have a pending flag on this answer"]

Here's me trying to at first tap on the selection with my touch screen (some feedback), then clicking it furiously with my mouse:

[image: tap tap tap tap click click click click click click click]

Usually when Stack Exchange wants to tell me "I can't let you do that, Dave" it'll be pretty explicit about it, and this isn't consistent with that kind of error handling. There were also no console errors.

Comment: I had a similar thing - I flagged it as not an answer, then realised I also wanted to flag it as offensive.

Comment: Can you check that this is still happening? I suspect its behaviour is/was related to already having a flag pending. Since the post's flags were automatically approved when enough of them auto-deleted the post, if that was the cause, you should be able to select the custom flag radio button now. (Regardless, lack of feedback would be a UX issue, yes! I just want to narrow down the causes.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I can indeed choose that reason now, with the answer deleted. ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNtqh.png))